# Send multiple files of different types via Intent using FileProvider

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to share both an image and an audio file via `Intent`, using a `FileProvider`. 
 
It works when I try to the send only one of the two files (they both work), **but** when I pass an array list containing the URIs of both files I get the following exception.

```
Writing exception to parcel      java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/fs_id from pid=27900, uid=10062 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
      at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:605)
      at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:480)
      at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:211)
      at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

This is how I set up the provider in the `AndroidManifest`:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.mypackage.mybeautifulprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

and this is how I create the `Intent`:

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();

// image file
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.mypackage.mybeautifulprovider", imageFile);
uris.add(uri);

// audio file
uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.mypackage.mybeautifulprovider", audioFile);
uris.add(uri);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

// start intent
....
```

Comment: Use `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` for sending multiple things, not `ACTION_SEND`. Even if you get past the permission issue, clients will not be expecting an array in `EXTRA_STREAM` with `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: When I try to use `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`, this exception is thrown by the receiving app: `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{efa0d77 24711:com.google.android.gm/u0a64} (pid=24711, uid=10064) that is not exported from uid 10105`

Comment: Hmmm... I was hoping that the `Intent` flags would ripple out to the elements of the array for `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`, the way they do for individual `Uri` values in `ACTION_SEND`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [Forget the Storage Permission talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C28pvd2plBA&feature=youtu.be&t=1591), `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` only apply to the URI set in `setData()`. If you need multiple Uris, they need to be added as ClipData:

```
ClipData clipData = ClipData.newRawUri(null, imageUri);
clipData.addItem(new ClipData.Item(audioUri));
intent.setClipData(clipData);
```

Note that [setClipData()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClipData(android.content.ClipData)) was only added in API 16.

Comment: When using clip data I get this exception: `Writing exception to parcel
                                                  java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/fs_id from pid=31664, uid=10062 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()`, which I guess is relative to Android Marshmallow permission system

Comment: @AlessandroRoaro - so the other app is attempting to read from the MediaProvider? That doesn't seem to be something tied to your app does it as the FileProvider SecurityException is gone?

Comment: The point is that if the other app hasn't allowed the permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, then it will throw this exception

Comment: @AlessandroRoaro - that certainly seems like a problem with whatever the receiving app you are using. Of course, if it works with the single URI case, then there is no difference in access to the data you provide in the multiple URI case - just a difference in the other app's code.

Comment: That also happens while using normal URIs instead of a FileProvider. You get the PermissionDenial exception

Comment: @AlessandroRoaro - alas, your app cant' fix other apps problems. If they have access to the entire audio file you provide (which, they do as you are not seeing a FileProvider related SecurityException), then it is up to that app to extract information from the file. Using MediaProvider and the storage permission is one way to do that.